# Using Square in Salesforce with XMLHttpRequest or JQuery Ajax to post transactions

Tags: square-connect

I'm trying to use Square in a Salesforce Apex page. I have successfully created the sqpaymentform, get the nonce and post the page back to itself. When the page post back to itself I want to invoke either javascript XMLHTTPRequest or JQuery Ajax call to post the sale instead of using Unirest. I'm tried both the Personal and Sandbox access tokens in the header and I keep getting 401 Unauthorized. Has any used JQuery or XMLHttpRequest to post payments to Square? If so how did you do it?

Comment: Can you verify that you're using the correct `applicationId` in `SqPaymentForm.js`, and `access_token` when you're calling `Charge`? They must both be production or sandbox tokens. This is the most common reason for 401 Unauthorized.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. Can't be done via XMLHTTPRequest, JQUery or AngularJS. Yes, the form sqPaymentform is generated but the second step, processing the card can't be done using async javascript, even setting async = false does not work.  I completed the process using Salesforce APEX. Let me know if you want guidance on using Square credit card processing in Salesforce.